# Why does developer org say “Trial Expired” when I try to log in and how do I fix it?

Tags: isv, partner-communities

I have a `developer edition` I use to develop app. It was working fine, today then I try to log in it says `Trial Expired` as far as I know developer edition does not expire. Is `Request Partner Benefits` cause this problem? Because last time I log a case for `Request Partner Benefits`and they processed it.

I am unable login in my `partners.salesforce.com` to log a case.

Comment: Did you sign up for Salesforce DX? That has a trial period of only one month.

Comment: I was using it for last 9 , 10 months, That issue never occure

Comment: Did you enable the Salesforce DX Trial?

Comment: no didnt enable that

Answer (score 0):

your account is expired due to it has not been used for last 6 month;
it can be fixed by 2 ways:

- create new one account;
- ask salesforce support to restore the account, short instruction from email:
  You can reactivate a locked org by opening a case with Customer Support via the Help & Training portal. Once an org has been deleted, it cannot be reactivated.

thanks,

Comment: How do you log a support ticket in Help & Training when you need to log in first and the account is locked?